# Close/Open Excel Column Groups via ActiveX in Matlab

Tags: excel, vba, matlab, activex, excel-2016

I am struggling with an ActiveX problem. Usually, I find some help on the Internet or by recording a macro and somehow translating it to ActiveX, but I couldn't find anything for this particular challenge.

I have a huge amount of data that I'm writing to excel from Matlab. Everything works fine. I also group the data into different categories, which looks something like that (just a very short example):

```
excel = actxserver('excel.application');
wkbk  = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileNme);
sheet = wkbk.Sheets.Item(sheetNme);

sheet.Range(['A:J']).Columns.Group;
sheet.Range(['L:O']).Columns.Group;
sheet.Range(['Q:Z']).Columns.Group;
...
sheet.Range(['FG:FL']).Columns.Group;
```

There is always a column between two groups that represents the category. And there are some sub groups, too, which is why, in total, I have 3 group layers in Excel. It looks like this:

[image]

After Matlab is done and I open the Excel File, all groups are open. However, often, I'm interested in one of the last groups. So, it would be more convenient **if I could** **close all groups and sub groups via ActiveX**.

I recorded the steps I need via the macro recorder and it should be something like:

```
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
```

I tried this:

```
sheet.Outline.ShowLevels.ColumnLevels = 2;
sheet.Outline.ShowLevels.ColumnLevels = 1;
```

That doesn't work. Neither does:

```
sheet.Outline.ShowLevels(0,2);
sheet.Outline.ShowLevels(0,1);
```

That's just a logical. And I guess it doesn't work because ShowLevels is not a function.

Does anybody have any idea how to translate this?

Thank you

Laura

Comment: (untested) looks like you might want [`Range.ShowDetail` (docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.showdetail) ref this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528780/hide-unhide-specific-group

Comment: Thank you @Wolfie. I posted an answer with the solution I found using your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Wolfie for your comment. It was the hint I needed. After a bit of trial & error, I found the right code.

Btw, in my example above I used

```
sheet.Outline.SummaryColumn = 'xlSummaryOnLeft';
```

to move the Grouping-Button to the left. By default it's on the right. In this case and referencing to my grouping example above, I had to use

```
sheet.Range(['K:K']).Columns.ShowDetail = 0;
sheet.Range(['P:P']).Columns.ShowDetail = 0;
...
```

to close the groups. And it's very important that this code goes after code that formats columns (especially ColumnWidth). Otherwise the groups will expand again and it would seem that nothing had changed.

Thanks again! :)

Comment: Great, you can mark your own answer as "accepted" to resolve this post :)